# PdfPopupAnnotation parent not accessible after copying page to other document

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, pdf-annotations

I'm copying annotated PDF pages from one document to another. The odd thing I'm experiencing is that in the new document, I can't access the parent of the `PdfPopupAnnotation`s:

```
public class CopyPdfTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument inputDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("src/test/resources/input.pdf"));
        PdfDocument outputDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("/tmp/output.pdf"));

        // Copy pages
        for (int i = 1; i <= inputDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            inputDoc.copyPagesTo(i, i, outputDoc);
        }

        // Re-open outputDoc to eliminate the possibility the problem stems from
        // it being opened in writing mode
        outputDoc.close();
        outputDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("/tmp/output.pdf"));

        // Step through the PdfPopupAnnotations in both documents and check for their parents
        for (PdfDocument doc : new PdfDocument[] { inputDoc, outputDoc } ) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= inputDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                for (PdfAnnotation annot : doc.getPage(i).getAnnotations()) {
                    if (annot instanceof PdfPopupAnnotation) {
                        // This prints null for popups from the outputDoc
                        System.out.println(((PdfPopupAnnotation) annot).getParentObject());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following output when processing a PDF with one `/Square` annotation (first line prints popup annotation parent from original PDF, second line prints `null` for output PDF):

```
<</AP <</N 10 0 R >> /C [0.898026 0.133331 0.215683 ] /Contents test /CreationDate D:20180107105025+01'00' /F 4 /M D:20180107105029+01'00' /NM 8a233cc7-ed2f-48bf-91f2-a46cecf15160 /P 9 0 R /Popup 16 0 R /RC <?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:18.9.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2" ><p dir="ltr"><span dir="ltr" style="font-size:10.5pt;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal">test</span></p></body> /RD [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ] /Rect [84.7495 636.205 191.876 764.21 ] /Subj Rectangle /Subtype /Square /T tom /Type /Annot >>
null
```

I find this especially odd as looking at an uncompressed example PDF, the parent reference `4 0 R` remains intact, and the referenced `/Square` annotation remains present as `4 0 obj`.

**input.pdf**

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
5 0 obj 
<<
/M (D:20180107100338+01'00')
/NM (68bd5c7e-3071-4b10-83ad-6bb2e75a8f3d)
/Subtype /Popup
/Type /Annot
/Parent 4 0 R
/Open false
/F 28
/Rect [352.966 707.883 532.966 827.883]
/P 3 0 R
>>
endobj 
6 0 obj 
<<
/FormType 1
/Subtype /Form
/Type /XObject
/BBox [115.975 693.768 179.508 827.883]
/Length 69
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 -115.975 -693.768]
>>
stream
1.000 0.000 0.000 RG
2 w
0 J
0 j
116.975 694.768 61.534 132.115 re
S

endstream 
endobj 
4 0 obj 
<<
/Subtype /Square
/RD [0 0 0 0]
/RC (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:11.0.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2"><p dir="ltr"><span style="text-align:left;font-size:13pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#000000;font-family:Arial">test</span></p></body>)
/T (thw)
/Contents (test)
/Rect [115.975 693.768 179.508 827.883]
/CA 1
/P 3 0 R
/M (D:20180107100342+01'00')
/Type /Annot
/NM (fd33d765-e844-4226-aff8-3ef81361e787)
/F 4
/BS 
<<
/W 2
/S /S
>>
/AP 
<<
/N 6 0 R
>>
/C [1 0 0]
/Popup 5 0 R
/Subj (Rectangle)
/CreationDate (D:20180107100338+01'00')
>>
endobj 
8 0 obj 
<<
/OPM 1
/Type /ExtGState
>>
endobj 
7 0 obj 
<<
/R7 8 0 R
>>
endobj 
9 0 obj 
<<
/Length 30
>>
stream
q 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 cm
/R7 gs
Q

endstream 
endobj 
3 0 obj 
<<
/pdftk_PageNum 1
/Annots [4 0 R 5 0 R]
/Resources 
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF]
/ExtGState 7 0 R
>>
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Contents 9 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj 
1 0 obj 
<<
/Kids [3 0 R]
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
>>
endobj 
11 0 obj 
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj 
12 0 obj 
<<
/ModDate (D:20180107101601+01'00')
/CreationDate (D:20180107101601+01'00')
/Creator (pdftk 2.02 - www.pdftk.com)
/Producer (itext-paulo-155 \(itextpdf.sf.net-lowagie.com\))
>>
endobj xref
0 13
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001472 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001293 00000 n 
0000000460 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000220 00000 n 
0000001177 00000 n 
0000001130 00000 n 
0000001210 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001531 00000 n 
0000001583 00000 n 
trailer

<<
/Info 12 0 R
/ID [<23bde7d1ea6b4f52b55dc534b36f8d41><e031fe688c87cb2303e0a99487c3025e>]
/Root 11 0 R
/Size 13
>>
startxref
1779
%%EOF
```

**output.pdf**

```
%PDF-1.7
%âãÏÓ
5 0 obj 
<<
/M (D:20180107100338+01'00')
/NM (68bd5c7e-3071-4b10-83ad-6bb2e75a8f3d)
/Subtype /Popup
/Type /Annot
/Parent 4 0 R
/Open false
/F 28
/Rect [352.966 707.883 532.966 827.883]
/P 3 0 R
>>
endobj 
6 0 obj 
<<
/FormType 1
/Subtype /Form
/Type /XObject
/BBox [115.975 693.768 179.508 827.883]
/Length 69
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 -115.975 -693.768]
>>
stream
1.000 0.000 0.000 RG
2 w
0 J
0 j
116.975 694.768 61.534 132.115 re
S

endstream 
endobj 
4 0 obj 
<<
/Subtype /Square
/RD [0 0 0 0]
/RC (<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:11.0.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2"><p dir="ltr"><span style="text-align:left;font-size:13pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#000000;font-family:Arial">test</span></p></body>)
/T (thw)
/Contents (test)
/Rect [115.975 693.768 179.508 827.883]
/CA 1
/P 3 0 R
/M (D:20180107100342+01'00')
/Type /Annot
/NM (fd33d765-e844-4226-aff8-3ef81361e787)
/F 4
/BS 
<<
/W 2
/S /S
>>
/AP 
<<
/N 6 0 R
>>
/C [1 0 0]
/Popup 5 0 R
/Subj (Rectangle)
/CreationDate (D:20180107100338+01'00')
>>
endobj 
7 0 obj 
<<
/M (D:20180107100338+01'00')
/NM (68bd5c7e-3071-4b10-83ad-6bb2e75a8f3d)
/Subtype /Popup
/Open false
/Type /Annot
/F 28
/Rect [352.966 707.883 532.966 827.883]
/P 3 0 R
>>
endobj 
9 0 obj 
<<
/OPM 1
/Type /ExtGState
>>
endobj 
8 0 obj 
<<
/R7 9 0 R
>>
endobj 
10 0 obj 
<<
/Length 30
>>
stream
q 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 cm
/R7 gs
Q

endstream 
endobj 
3 0 obj 
<<
/pdftk_PageNum 1
/Annots [4 0 R 7 0 R]
/Resources 
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF]
/ExtGState 8 0 R
>>
/Contents 10 0 R
/Parent 1 0 R
/Type /Page
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj 
1 0 obj 
<<
/Kids [3 0 R]
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
>>
endobj 
12 0 obj 
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj 
13 0 obj 
<<
/ModDate (D:20180107101427+01'00')
/CreationDate (D:20180107101427+01'00')
/Creator (pdftk 2.02 - www.pdftk.com)
/Producer (itext-paulo-155 \(itextpdf.sf.net-lowagie.com\))
>>
endobj xref
0 14
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001665 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001485 00000 n 
0000000460 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000220 00000 n 
0000001130 00000 n 
0000001368 00000 n 
0000001321 00000 n 
0000001401 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000001724 00000 n 
0000001776 00000 n 
trailer

<<
/Info 13 0 R
/ID [<09baf689039bb6015d4c428111e4ee72><684b5613b1931e88255384276dcaceb1>]
/Root 12 0 R
/Size 14
>>
startxref
1972
%%EOF
```

Any hints to why this is so and how to make the parent accessible by iText?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: @mkl It's quoted above (copy&paste works). I tried with PDFs generated from Adobe Reader and Foxit - there's no difference in the outcome.

Comment: *"copy&paste works"* - I tried it for both files but each time Adobe Reader says "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired." Actually this didn't surprise, copy&paste hardly ever works for binary files, I just tried hoping you'd have properly tested across platforms and browsers and editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the OP did not provide the PDF files in binary form, so I could not simply check the following; looking at the data, though, a difference is obvious...

The popup object in your `input.pdf` has a **Parent** entry:

```
5 0 obj 
<<
/M (D:20180107100338+01'00')
/NM (68bd5c7e-3071-4b10-83ad-6bb2e75a8f3d)
/Subtype /Popup
/Type /Annot
/Parent 4 0 R
/Open false
/F 28
/Rect [352.966 707.883 532.966 827.883]
/P 3 0 R
>>
endobj
```

In your `output.pdf`, on the other hand, the popup object doesn't:

```
7 0 obj 
<<
/M (D:20180107100338+01'00')
/NM (68bd5c7e-3071-4b10-83ad-6bb2e75a8f3d)
/Subtype /Popup
/Open false
/Type /Annot
/F 28
/Rect [352.966 707.883 532.966 827.883]
/P 3 0 R
>>
```

This also matches the iText 7 code of the `getParent` method:

```
public PdfDictionary getParentObject() {
    return getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Parent);
}

public PdfAnnotation getParent() {
    if (parent == null) {
        parent = makeAnnotation(getParentObject());
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Thus, *to make the parent accessible by iText*, make sure the popup annotation has a **Parent** entry!

---

Yes, I know, the **Parent** entry is optional. But the `getParent` does not claim that it determines the actual parent object, it merely returns the object referenced by the **Parent** entry.

---

Another issue in your output.pdf:

- the page object clearly indicates that its annotations are in objects 4 and 7;
- but the annotation in 4 references an annotation in 5 as pop-up, an annotation not even associated with the page;
- the pop-up in 5 (the one not associated with the page) references 4 as its parent; the pop-up in 7 (the one that is associated with the page) does not have a **Parent** entry.

When analysing the files you probably did not look at the annotations of the page but merely at the pop-up/parent relations between annotation objects and, therefore, thought your pop-up has a parent entry...

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, @mkl. So the problem boils down to 1. why iText creates this additional Popup, 2. removes the Parent entry during copying, 3. only sees 2 annotations when iterating over them while there are actually 3 on the page of the output PDF. I guess I'll open a new question for these more specific points.

Comment: *"only sees 2 annotations when iterating over them while there are actually 3 on the page of the output PDF"* - this is simple: There only are *two* annotations as the page annotation array only references two annotations. The third annotation, even though it is referenced by one of the on-page annotations as popup, is not in that array and, therefore, not on that page. The other two issues indeed should be looked into...

Comment: The OP opened [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48150167/1729265) for these more specific points.